# Delphi compile errors

Tags: delphi

I am new to Pascal and I am trying to write a program for my college assignment, but i am getting compile errors which say:

> [dcc32 Error] Project2.dpr(36): E2029 ';' expected but '.' found
>
> [dcc32 Error] Project2.dpr(38): E2029 Declaration expected but end of file found

Here is the program I have written:

```pascal
program masquerader;  //program name

Var //Declaring variables

  Salary:integer; //Declared Salary as integer

procedure Sleep(milliseconds: Cardinal); stdcall;//Added sleep as a procedure for delay

Begin      //Begins the program

  Writeln('Enter Your Salary please user...'); //Outputs line Enter Your salary please user...
  Readln(Salary); //Recieves the value and declares the integer value to salary
  Writeln('Processing your input...'); //Outputs line to Let the user know its being processed
  Sleep(4000);  //4 second delay
  Writeln('Done!');
  If (Salary>=5000) AND (Salary<=8000) Then //Conditions are being test for the requirements for each section
    Writeln('Thanks for your Input file should be ready in a second'); //  Outputs this line to let the user know it is ready in a second
    Writeln('Congratulations!,You are eligible to play in poison');    //Outputs the section that matches the user's salary(5000-8000)
  If (Salary>=3000) AND (Salary<=5000) Then //Conditions are being test for the requirements for each section
    Writeln('Thanks for your Input file should be ready in a second'); //  Outputs this line to let the user know it is ready in a second
    Writeln('Congratulations!,You are eligible to play in Blue devils');//Outputs the section that matches the user's salary(3000-5000)
  If (Salary<3000) Then  //Conditions are being test for the requirements for each section
    Writeln('Thanks for your Input file should be ready in a second'); //  Outputs this line to let the user know it is ready in a second
    Writeln('Congratulations!,You are eligible to play in The poor man section');//Outputs the section that matches the user's salary(x<=3000)
    Writeln('Written by Timothy Adams');
    Writeln('Fatima College 4-1');
    Readln; //Declares the end of the read line

End.   //End of program       //Program written by timothy Adams
```

Comment: I fixed it by removing the procedure and the sleep line but i need it for the assignment...is there any other way to add a delay? around 5 seconds delay

Comment: Get sleep by using the function declared in Windows.pas. So remove the declaration of sleep in your code and use Windows.

Comment: So this user deleted his account. I wonder why SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code.

You are declaring a new function `Sleep()` without telling the compiler where its implementation is. So the compiler thinks your entire code between `begin` and `end` is the implementation. That is why you are getting the errors, because you are terminating the function implementation with `end.` instead of `end;`

The [`Sleep()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep) function your are trying to use is already declared in the RTL's `Windows` unit, use that instead. But, if you want to declare `Sleep()` manually then you need to include an [`external`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions_(Delphi)#External_Declarations) clause to tell the compiler that the implementation is located in a DLL (specifically, in kernel32.dll). That will then allow the compiler to treat your `begin`/`end` block as the program implementation instead.

Also, Delphi code blocks are not specified by indentation, like you are assuming. You need to use explicit `begin`/`end` statements to group statements together.

Try this instead:

```pascal
program masquerader; //program name

uses
  Windows;

Var //Declaring variables
  Salary:integer; //Declared Salary as integer

//procedure Sleep(milliseconds: Cardinal); stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll'; //Added sleep as a procedure for delay

Begin //Begins the program

  Writeln('Enter Your Salary please user...'); //Outputs line Enter Your salary please user...
  Readln(Salary); //Recieves the value and declares the integer value to salary Writeln('Processing your input...'); //Outputs line to Let the user know its being processed
  Sleep(4000); //4 second delay
  Writeln('Done!');

  If (Salary>=5000) AND (Salary<=8000) Then //Conditions are being test for the requirements for each section
  Begin
    Writeln('Thanks for your Input file should be ready in a second'); // Outputs this line to let the user know it is ready in a second
    Writeln('Congratulations!,You are eligible to play in poison'); //Outputs the section that matches the user's salary(5000-8000)
  End;

  If (Salary>=3000) AND (Salary<=5000) Then //Conditions are being test for the requirements for each section
  Begin
    Writeln('Thanks for your Input file should be ready in a second'); // Outputs this line to let the user know it is ready in a second
    Writeln('Congratulations!,You are eligible to play in Blue devils');//Outputs the section that matches the user's salary(3000-5000)
  End;

  If (Salary<3000) Then //Conditions are being test for the requirements for each section
  Begin
    Writeln('Thanks for your Input file should be ready in a second'); // Outputs this line to let the user know it is ready in a second
    Writeln('Congratulations!,You are eligible to play in The poor man section');//Outputs the section that matches the user's salary(x<=3000)
  End;

  Writeln('Written by Timothy Adams');
  Writeln('Fatima College 4-1');
  Readln; //Declares the end of the read line

End. //End of program
//Program written by timothy Adams
```

On a side note, your code is not handling salaries above 8000.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked very well thank you, im new to programming and this was my first project which i find pascal being an outdated language but thank you for your help.

Comment: "*i find pascal being an outdated language*" - hardly, certainly not the Delphi flavor of Pascal, anyway. Delphi is in the top 20 popular languages of the [TIOBE index](https://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/), for instance

Comment: i didnt know that honestly